# Center Facebook "Send to Messenger" button and text

Tags: javascript, css, facebook

Is there a way to center the "Send to Messenger" button so it will be centered with the "Logged in as" text?

This kind of having a negative effect on the user experience with our mobile UI, and we've tried all kinds of CSS tricks with no success.

I understand that iframe's CSS may only be altered with JS if the iframe is loading from within the same domain, so its not a possible fix as well.

FB default:
[image: Default]

We want it like this:
[image: Centered button and text]

```
.text-center {
text-align: center;
}

.btn-send-fb {
   width: 180px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}


<div class=“text-center btn-send-fb”>
           <div class=“fb-send-to-messenger”
                data-messenger_app_id=“1000000000000”
                data-page_id=“1000000000000"
                data-color=“blue”
                data-size=“xlarge”
                data-cta_text=“SEND_THIS_TO_ME”>
           </div>
 </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Code? What do you currently have and what have you tried?

Comment: There is no way. You are not allowed to modify the look & feel of any of the FB social plugins beyond what official options they offer for such purposes to begin with, and since they render inside an iframe with content loaded from a different origin, no JS or CSS is allowed to “reach inside” either.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure. Thanks!